# Is there any prevailing way to compute the digest of a JSON?

Tags: json, hash, digest

I want to get the same digest value when **contents** of two JSONs are equal. For example, I want the following two to generate the same digest value although spaces, newlines and the key order are different.

```js
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

```js
{"key2":"value2", "key1":"value1"}
```

About a year ago, I wrote my own Java implementation ([nv-digest](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-digest)) which can be used like below.

```java
// Compute SHA-1 of two JSONs.
// 'result1' and 'result2' will have the same value.
String json1 = "{ \"key1\":\"value1\", \"key2\":\"value2\" }";
String json2 = "{ \"key2\":\"value2\", \"key1\":\"value1\" }";
String result1 = Digest.getInstanceSHA1().updateJson(json1).digestAsString();
String result2 = Digest.getInstanceSHA1().updateJson(json2).digestAsString();
```

However, if there is a prevailing way to do the same thing, I want to use it. Could you recommend any library or existing specification?